# Vuex without Vue?

Tags: node.js, vuex

I'd like to use Vuex to power a server-side application that doesn't use Vue. Is this possible?

```
const Vuex = require('vuex');

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        potatoes: 1,
    },
    getters: {
        doublePotatoes(state) {
            return state.potatoes * 2;
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        addPotato(state) {
            state.potatoes += 1;
        },
    }
});

store.watch((state, getters) => getters.doublePotatoes, console.log);
store.commit("addPotato");
```

Here's the error I get:

```
$ node index.js
/private/tmp/vtest/node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.common.js:99
if (!condition) { throw new Error(("[vuex] " + msg)) }
                    ^

Error: [vuex] must call Vue.use(Vuex) before creating a store instance.
    at assert (/private/tmp/vtest/node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.common.js:99:27)
    at new Store (/private/tmp/vtest/node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.common.js:279:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/tmp/vtest/index.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wound up adding Vue without creating a Vue app:

```
const Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(Vuex);
```

My tiny test store works now. I don't know if `Vue.use(Vuex)` without creating a Vue app will cause any problems.

Of note for server-side use cases, Vuex doesn't call my watcher for *every* commit; it batches changes and calls the watcher once. I don't see this documented.

Comment: How's this working out for you? I like your style! State management is also a problem for server apps.